# android fragments are not removed when app goes to backgroung via notification

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am writing an android appliction. the application has a main activity the main activity has a tabhost that contains 5 tabs and a `framelayout` that holds `fragments`.

[image: everything except the tab is a fragment]

when each tab is clicked the `fragment` in the `fragment` in the frame layout is replaced by the respective `fragment`.

now the i move out from the app by selecing some notification. and retuen to the app from the homescreen again the the `activity` starts from the first. and loads the first `fragment`(this is not visible but it can be seen from the log cat that `onCreate` of the main actviy is called). but the `fragment` that is visible is the `fragment` from where i went to the notification.
any idea why it is happening so??

CODE

```
    tabChanged= new OnTabChangeListener() {

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            tab_Change(tabId);

        }
    };
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(tabChanged);


void tab_Change(String ss)
    {
     if(ss.equalsIgnoreCase("TRIAL"))
     {
         selected_tab=0;

         View tab_view =mTabHost.getCurrentTabView();
            tab_view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menutab_bg);

         if(arr_frag1==null)
         {
             addTrialTab();

         }
         else
         {
                ShowFragmentByIndex(selected_tab);
         }

     }
```

`... etc }`

```
public void addTrialTab()
{
    FragmentManager fm =  getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment frag_first = new TrailMainFrag();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag_first,"TRIAL0").commit();
    AddFragmentid("TRIAL0");
}

 void ShowFragmentByIndex(int index)
    {
        FragmentManager fm =  getSupportFragmentManager();
        String temp_fr = "";
        int size = 0;

        if(index == 0)
        {
            size = arr_frag1.size();
            temp_fr =(String)arr_frag1.get(size-1);
        }
... etc FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            Fragment fr = fm.findFragmentByTag(temp_fr);

            if(fr!=null)
            {
            ft.attach(fr);
            }
            ft.commit();
            }
```

Comment: Are you adding fragments via FragmentTransaction.add() or FragmentTransaction.replace()?

Comment: FragmentTransaction.add() is used.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().isEmpty() returns true. i think when the activiy is stared again a new instance is created. so the old fragment cannot be replace.

Comment: isEmpty() returns true because the transaction is empty, not the container.  That is not the proper use of isEmpty().

Comment: Can you add the code where you add your fragments.  It's getting a bit difficult to guess the solution.

Comment: added the code in the question.